# RTL8188C USB WiFi Dongle

Tags: drivers, compiling

I'm trying to install the drivers for a wifi dongle but so far have failed.

Could somone please tell me how to do this?

The manufacture supplied a CD with the following driver

```
RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
```

with instructions to compile the drivers, but when I tried to do this I got errors.

lsusb gives

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

giving

```
E: Unable to locate package firmware-realtek
```

Compiling the code gave the following output:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-71-generic/build M=/home/terry/rtl8188C  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-71-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/hal_intf.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/hal_com.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: In function ‘rtw_proc_init_one’:
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
   ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
           ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_read_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
   ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
         ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:326:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("log_level", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:332:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   entry->write_proc = proc_set_log_level;
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:348:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   padapter->dir_dev = create_proc_entry(dev->name,
                     ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:379:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("write_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:385:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_write_reg;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:387:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("read_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:393:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_read_reg;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:396:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("fwstate", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:404:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sec_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:412:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mlmext_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:420:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("qos_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:427:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:434:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:441:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ap_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:448:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("adapter_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:455:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("trx_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:462:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:469:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:476:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:483:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:490:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:497:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:504:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:511:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:520:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:527:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump4", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:537:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("all_sta_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:555:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("best_channel", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:561:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_best_channel;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:564:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_signal", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:570:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_signal;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:572:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:578:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ht_enable;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:580:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("cbw40_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:586:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_cbw40_enable;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:588:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ampdu_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:594:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ampdu_enable;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:596:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_stbc", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:602:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_stbc;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:605:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("path_rssi", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:608:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("vid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:615:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("pid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:622:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rssi_disp", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:628:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rssi_disp;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:631:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sreset", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:637:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_sreset;
       ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: At top level:
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’) [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/terry/rtl8188C/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/terry/rtl8188C] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-71-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: You have a Ralink device. It makes no sense to install Realtek drivers.

Comment: @Chili555,

Thanks this worked perfectly for me. I was also able to give this information to a friend who was also struggling to find out how to do this.

How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @Pilot6

It makes sense to me when they use similar part numbers and an internet search produce a large number of links on this issue  to what can I can only describe as rubbish solutions that don't work.  

The expression can't see the wood for the trees springs to mind.

As this seems to be causing a lot of problems for Ubuntu users why isn't this driver part of the normal kernel release?

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

sudo apt-get update

This updates your sources for apt-get

Also your adapter is a Ralink, not Realtek, so try installing firmware for a Ralink adapter 
(Possibly "firmware-ralink" )